# Hadoop MapReduce: size of data processed in shuffle and reduce phase

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, shuffle

I am running a Hadoop MapReduce Java application on a cluster containing several AWS instances. I am wondering if it's possible to know the size of dataset in shuffle stage, namely, how much data in total is shuffled. Additionally, is it possible to know how much data is processed by each reducer task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to find this information from the JobTracker Web UI.

There is a counter named "Reduce shuffle bytes" that details the total bytes being shuffled - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4845 and the original linked ticket for further information.

For a per reducer count, drill down to a completed reducer task and examine this counter in isolation for the task

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. By the way, is it possible to get these data using java API instead of looking at web UI? I have a quite big job running, having hundreds of tasks, so it would be inefficient to collect data manually.

Comment: Sure, look at the JobClient class, specifically the getReduceTaskReports method - http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html#getReduceTaskReports(org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobID)

Answer (score 0):

You could go to the AWS EMR Job Screen and select the Job and then click on the "Debug" button. There you can view your syslog file. It has all the information about the Map and Reduce tasks. The values for all the Counters like "Reduce shuffle bytes", "Map output records" etc are dumped. You can also see the exact time taken by your program to execute and the number of Map tasks failed in the syslog.

Hope this helps. I would suggest when you create the job on AWS, set the Debug option on so that you could see this file, if you are not already doing so.